# Using subprocess in python with multiple values and same argument

Tags: python, subprocess, xargs, mp4box

This is my command

```
subprocess.call(["wine","MP4Box.exe","-add",outputdir+"tmp.m4a","-itags",'name=a',"-itags", "artist=b","-itags", "album_artist=c","-itags", "album=d","-itags", "created=2034","-itags", "genre=e","-new", "tmp23.m4a"])
```

In the output file i can get only genre, subprocess sends only the last "-itags" value.Anyway to make this work?

thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call` doesn't do any filtering - it merely constructs a string that can be executed by the shell. Try running the command in a shell normally, you'll get the same result. Once you can get it running in a shell, fix your `subprocess.call` accordingly. (eg: read the docs for MP4Box and see how it handles the above/what arguments it expects to do what you want (or even if it can do it in one go))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/) the parameter should be passed like this

> -itags tag1[:tag2]

So you may try to do it like so

```
subprocess.call(["wine","MP4Box.exe","-add",outputdir+"tmp.m4a","-itags","name=a:artist=b" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
outputdir = "output"

subprocess.call([
    "wine", "MP4Box.exe", "-add", outputdir + "/tmp.m4a",
    "-itags", "name={name}:artist={artist}:album_artist={album_artist}:album={album}:created={created}:genre={genre}".format(
        name="a",
        artist="b",
        album_artist="c",
        album="d",
        created=2034,
        genre="e"
    ),
    "-new", "tmp23.m4a"
])
```

From the [docs](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/).

Note that the tags cannot contain the `:` character as this will break the command.

Comment: Any reason you're suggesting to use string formatting here? Using a list of arguments is the correct way as it'll correctly escape the arguments so it doesn't cause issues in the shell...  Think of an outputdir with a space in it etc...

Comment: @JonClements I did not think of that, I will correct it.

Comment: Nice... you could also remove the `**{` unpacking for the dict and just use `.format(name='a', artist='b')` etc... but functionally it'd be the same...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for your suggestions, it is indeed cleaner!